# file missing or inaccessible in processing

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

```
public void setup(){
    String[] rows = loadStrings("data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv");
    lifeExpByCountry = lifeExpByCountryFromCSV(rows);
    countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "data/countries.geo.json");
    countryMarkers = MapUtils.createSimpleMarkers(countries);
    size(800,600,OPENGL);
    map = new UnfoldingMap(this,50,50,700,500, new Google.GoogleMapProvider());
    MapUtils.createDefaultEventDispatcher(this,map);
    map.addMarkers(countryMarkers);
    shadeCountries();
}
```

I gave the loadstrings method inside the setup(). but still im gettin the file missing error. Im runnning OS X.

Comment: okay, please post what `loadStrings(String path)` do.

Comment: @jmcg Notice the [tag:processing] tag. The `loadStrings()` function is a Processing function. You can read about it in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `loadStrings("data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv")`, try `loadStrings("LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv")` without the `data` part.

Reading [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html), it says that files are loaded from the `data` directory automatically, so you don't have to specify the `data` part. With your code, it's looking for `data/data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv`, which doesn't exist.

If that doesn't work, or for future debugging, go to the menu `Sketch` > `Show Sketch Folder`. That should contain a data directory, and that should contain the file you're trying to load. Make absolutely certain that the file is there, has the correct permissions, and everything is spelled correctly.

Comment: No it doesn't work. Where can i find the sketch folder?

Comment: @GowthamBk Like I said, go to the menu in the Processing editor, go to sketch, and then show sketch folder. That will open a file explorer to your sketch directory.

Comment: I have posted the erros I am getting

Answer (score 0):

Check the path where your LifeExpectancy.java file is located, you would be having it in src folder. So the correct path will be
 countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "../data/countries.geo.json");

There are few more lines specifying the path in the same way, all need to be changed.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah. that problem is resolved now. But, Iam getting Animation thread exception error in the same line.

Comment: Is the exception mentioned as NumberFormatException?

I have single stepped and not able to find the line from where this is coming.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<String, Float> lifeExpByCountryFromCSV(String[] rows){
    Map<String, Float> lifeExpMap = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    for(String row : rows){
        String[] columns = row.split(",");
        if(columns[5]!=null){
            float value = Float.parseFloat(columns[5]);
            lifeExpMap.put(columns[4], value);
        }
    }
    return lifeExpMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the file paths as

```
lifeExpByCountry = loadLifeExpectancyFromCSV("LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv");
countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, "countries.geo.json");
```

and define the function loadLifeExpectancyFromCSV as

```
private Map<String, Float> loadLifeExpectancyFromCSV(String fileName) {

    Map<String, Float> lifeExpMap = new HashMap<String, Float>();
    String[] rows = loadStrings(fileName);

    for (String row: rows) {
        String[] columns = row.split(",");
        try{
            float value = Float.parseFloat(columns[5]);
            lifeExpMap.put(columns[4], value);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println(columns[4] + " has missing data");
        }
    }

    return lifeExpMap;
}
```

It should work. The remaining issue after using the correct file paths is the handling of the lines without life expectancy data in the csv files.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but try

```
countries = GeoJSONReader.loadData(this, this.sketchPath("../data/countries.geo.json"));
```

This worked for me.